Product of two ergodic probabilities
I have two probabilities $P_1$ and $P_2$, on the space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$, equipped with the shifts $\theta_n(x) = \theta_n((x_j)_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}) = (x_{j+n})_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} = x_{\cdot+n}.$ They are both stationary and ergodic, ergodic in the sense that the invariant $\sigma$-algebras are trivial, I denote them $\mathcal{I}_{P_1}$ and $\mathcal{I}_{P_2}$. I'm trying to prove that $P = P_1\otimes P_2$ is ergodic for the shifts $\theta_n((x,y))=(x_{\cdot+n},y_{\cdot+n})$.
My trial: let $\mathcal{A} = \{A\in(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z})^{\otimes2}:\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},~\theta_n(A) = A,~ P(A) = 0 \text{ or } 1\}.$ I want to prove that $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{I}_P$. We have that $\mathcal{A}\supseteq\mathcal{I}_{P_1}\times \mathcal{I}_{P_2}$ and since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, this implies $\mathcal{A} \supseteq \sigma(\mathcal{I}_{P_1}\times \mathcal{I}_{P_2})$. This concludes if we prove that $\sigma(\mathcal{I}_{P_1}\times \mathcal{I}_{P_2})\supseteq \mathcal{I}_{P}$ (I don't know how to prove that).

I think what you're trying to prove is not true, but I'm having difficulty reading what is written after "My trial" due to latex.  Isn't this false for the same reason that a cross product of an irrational rotation with itself is not ergodic?  Suppose $P_1$ is the probability on the shift space of 0's and 1's that generates an irrational rotation.  Just let $P_2 = P_1$.  Now, $P$ will not be ergodic, since the cross product of the rotations is not ergodic.  I think this can be made precise by considering a measure theoretic isomorphism between the spaces, [0,1]x[0,1] and your sequence pairs.

I think you need to assume weak mixing for at least one of the measures in order for this to be true.
